# How is the rating calculated in PUBG Mobile?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds, mobile

How is the rating (B,B<sup>+</sup>,A,A<sup>+</sup>,S,S<sup>+</sup>,Ss,Ss<sup>+</sup>,sSs) computed? In the screenshot below, there seems to be five metrics: survive, kills, support, supplies, and damage.

[image: Hey look I won... mmmm... chicken dinner!]

How is each one computed? I am curious about this because I don't know what "support" is referring to (EDIT: It has been renamed to "heal", and is tied to much health is restored during a match), and I am not sure why I didn't get full marks for "survive."

Answer (score 2):

Here is a step by step breakdown of the five metrics:

#### Survival

This is the most important factor in calculating your grade as it is worth twice as much as the others. This mainly depends on two key factors- Your **survival time**, and **how many people die around you**, if you dont kill them(Like landing in Pochinki)

#### Kills

This is the most obvious one as it depends on your kills. This depends on- Your **total kills** and your **K/D ratio**

#### Damage

This is self explanatory, damage depends on the **Damage** count(you got 325)

#### Support/Heal

In solo mode this depends only on **Health recovered** so you could intentionally damage yourself and heal to get this rating up.
In team mode this depends on two factors - **Health recovered** and **Reviving teammates**

#### Supplies

Supplies depends on **how rare the items are** which you pick up during the course of the game. So say a Kar98k would get you more Supplies points then a UZI. Also drop guns are worth more than their non drop counterparts.

---

At the end of this, your total rating is calculated by taking an average with 2x weightage for Survival, as mentioned.

I suppose the grade is then calculated the same way as school grades are, say SSS for 95+ rating(not exact figures).

Comment: How did you obtain this information? Experimentation? Documentation? It seems to check out, but I'm not sure how you arrived at the conclusions.

Comment: Just general information i have gathered from YouTube videos and experience ingame. So yeah, you could say experimentation. As PUBG mobile does not release official info like PUBG PC, any stats are just speculative or experimental.